# jq parse json problem cant get it to cycle loop

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

```
$ cat sax.json 

{"sax": [{"name": "mex20", "links": {"self": "http://website/catalog/sax/e49887"}, "tags": null, "enabled": true, "id": "e49887", "description": null}, {"name": "mex15", "links": {"self": "http://website/catalog/sax/e6de26"}, "tags": null, "enabled": true, "id": "e6de26", "description": null}, {"name": "mex56", "links": {"self": "http://website/catalog/sax/6cc093"}, "tags": null, "enabled": true, "id": "6cc093", "description": null}, {"name": "mex82", "links": {"self": "http://website/catalog/sax/89e0fe"}, "tags": null, "enabled": true, "id": "89e0fe", "description": null}]}
```

```
$ cat sax.json | jq  '.sax[] | select(.name | contains("mex"))' | jq .id

"e49887"
"e6de26"
"6cc093"
"89e0fe"
```

get_id.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array=($(jq .sax[].name sax.json ))

for i in "${array[@]}"
  do  cat sax.json | jq '.sax[] | select(.name | contains($i))' | jq .id
done
```

cycle doesnt work.
help please

Comment: Hi there! In addition to providing code, introducing the problem with a narrative is quite useful. Might I suggest you revise your question after a quick review of these helpful suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note that `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern and shouldn't ever be done. See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). For bash 4.x or later, use `readarray -t array < <(anything)` instead. (For older versions of bash, or if you need failed exit statuses from `anything` to be passed through, consider `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(anything && printf '\0')`)

Answer (score 1):

1. In the first query, there is no need to call jq twice; you can also avoid the UUOC:

```
< sax.json jq '.sax[] | select(.name | contains("mex")) | .id'
```

2. To make a shell variable's value available to jq, it is often best to use the --arg or --argjson command-line option. In your case, you'd want to use --argjson as $i already contains the enclosing quotation marks: `jq --argjson i "$i" ...`
3. Alternatively, you could set the array contents using `jq -r` to strip away the quotation marks, and then use `--arg i "$i"`.
4. The semantics of `contains` is rather complex; in general, to check if one string is a substring of another, it is better to use `startswith`, `index`, `test`, or similar, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq --argjson i "$i"
```

So `jq` can't be used in loop?
foreach?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a full answer. Can you expand this, perhaps copying the code from the question and modifying it so that it works as intended?